# Query for returning query plans from sql plan cache that contain 1 or more warnings?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, plan-cache

Is there a query I can run to return query plans from sql plan cache that contain 1 or more warnings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RedGate has a great article [Checking the Plan Cache Warnings for a SQL Server Database](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/checking-the-plan-cache-warnings-for-a-sql-server-database/) on how to query the plan cache to find plans with warnings.

Ultimately the warnings will be stored in the XML query_plan column of [sys.dm_exec_query_plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-plan-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) DMV.